# Debugging core dump files in gdb

Tags: gdb

Is there any way to show local variables states in gdb when a core dump file is loaded?

I had a core dump file loaded to gdb and switched to a certain frame (command: frame #), but I am not sure if it is possible to capture variables values without actually running it.

Some background, debugging some race condition which causes seg fault and is very hard to recreate. Running in gdb doesn't help reproduce too much. So my best chance would be somehow to figure out what variables states are based on the core file that I currently have.

Comment: `info locals` should do it.

Comment: FYI... when I tried to print in this case, gdb is complaining about program not being run.

Comment: It's possible you have a poorly-written pretty-printer installed which makes an inferior call during printing.  Try disabling pretty-printers before using "info locals"

Answer (score 1):

In case if someone looking for answer, this always works for me.

Move to the specific frame `p` followed by variable name

Example:

```
(gdb) frame 6 
#6  0x080f613d in add (add=0x8e5ae40) at main.c:6128**
6128            INSIST((error == 0) || (error == ENOENT));
(gdb) p error
$15 = 22
(gdb)
```

Hope this helps!